# Accessing RaspberryPi (Linux) from Android phone device

Tags: java, android, linux, portforwarding

With using Spring, I've made an app on my RaspberryPi that always when I type in my browser "rspi_ip/light", it switches on the LED. It works perfectly but I want to turn this LED on from my another Android app via Web. It is working when both Raspberry and phone are in the same network but I want to switch it on from any network. How I can make it accessible from anywhear and make it secure? I do not want to make any rules on my router this system has to be plug and play, just connecting raspberry to any network and be able to connect to it from my phone without any other apps if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports VPN you can set up it. Then you set up a VPN connection to your router on Android using some VPN client like OpenVPN. When you use this connection your phone will be in the same network as your device and you can use it.